# Infinite loop at the start of CLion build

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Whenever I try to build even the simplest program I get this message in the CLion massage window:

```
====================[ Build | untitled | Debug ]================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.3.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Mikołaj\CLionProjects\untitled\cmake-build-debug --target untitled -j 4
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/MikoĹ‚aj/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/MikoĹ‚aj/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug
```

And it goes infinitely. I can add that it occurred after installation, so maybe I didn't download something important. Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

I tried to reinstallation but it didn't work.

Comment: ***so maybe I didn't download something important*** Unlikely

Comment: Is your time correct on your computer? Is the time of your files correct?

Comment: @drescherjm Everything was right, but I figured that CLion doesn't accept non-english signs in the file path. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You may want to consider posting an answer to your own question to help future readers.

Comment: @MikołajKlint It is a common problem on Windows and Java-related stuff. Filepaths are finicky. A true ascii path(no spaces) is the safest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that CLion simply doesn't accept non-english signs in the file path, so be careful!

Comment: It's not CLion itself, it is NTFS/Java that trips up CLion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MinGW for building you can check this out. go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake and change the generator field to MinGW Makefiles and of course Toolchain to MinGW

[See Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVy2t.png)